# Maven build parameter to exclude a pom dependency

Tags: maven

I have a project which has some dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to have the possibility to include/exclude the dependency optionally in build time, and would be nice to have some parameter in my build, for instance `mvn clean package -mygroup` or something similar.
I have search in different mvn plugins configuration settings, but I didn´t find it.

Some ideas/inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full pom file? Otherwise it's hard to understand what you mean by `lib`?

Comment: I meant to include optionally the dependency without changing the pom. Does not matter where my lib is.

Comment: a maven `profile` should help you... `mvn clean package -Pmyprofile`... but you need to have control over the pom ;)

Comment: The idea is to be able to include/exclude different dependendies, and having a profile for each one wouldn´t be handy. That is why I am looking for something where I can say this dependency are excluded without modifiyn the pom.xml

Comment: The question is for what purpose do you need a depdency which is sometimes there and sometimes not? Sounds like [optional](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) see the docs.

Comment: According to http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/lt-scope-gt-provided-lt-scope-gt-vs-lt-optional-gt-true-lt-optional-gt-td2852244.html
This might be considered ad bad practice. Plus it is not exaclty what I am looking for: "optional=true means that a library is needed for compilation, but it 
is not necessary at runtime."
I might need it in run time

Comment: What is the advantage of excluding dependencies on the fly? The dependency:analyze goal gives you a good idea which dependencies should be included. Why do you want to modify that?